# Как установить кодировку utf-8 в phpmyadmin

Tags: php, кодировка, phpmyadmin, utf-8

`??????` вместо русских букв - помогите, пожалуйста.

```
<?php
    require "db.php";
    if(isset($_POST['send'])){
        if(trim($_POST['name']) == "" || trim($_POST['email']) == "" || trim($_POST['otziv']) == "")
        {
            $err = "Заполните все поля!";
        } else {
    $comments = R::dispense('comments');
    $comments->name = $_POST['name'];
    $comments->otziv = $_POST['otziv'];

    R::store($comments);
    header('location: forma.php');
}
}   
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы для подключения к БД используете PDO, то попробуйте в строке подключения дописать ;charset=utf8. Например $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8', $user, $pass);

Comment: Попробуй после $con  дописать mysqli_set_charset($con , "utf8");

Comment: Блин, чувак большое тебе спасибо), все работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно установить кодировку в соединении с БД.

Если для подключения к БД  использоваться PDO, то  в строке с опциями дописываем charset=UTF8 :

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DB;charset=UTF8");
```

Если mysqli в ООП стиле:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

В процедурном стиле:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'test');
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8")
```